# Should we think of lines as sets of points?

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory, soft-question

I recently heard about a mathematician who denied that lines are sets of points, preferring to think of them as objects to which points may be incident.

What are the advantages of this point of view? These might be practical advantages or philosophical advantages. I have a feeling that it may be less practical than the common idea of lines as sets of points. For example, if we want to consider a bijection from a line to the real numbers, we now have to consider the set of all points incident to the line.

Comment: Does he really "deny" that lines are sets of points? because thats just the definition, and sure you can use other definitions, but you can't deny a definition (except for example NJ Wildberger, but don't take that guy too seriously)

Comment: I think he was denying it in a semantic sense.

Comment: There is not enough context here. Sometimes it's better to do it, other times it's not.  *What* are you trying to do with your lines? *What* is the context in which you even have an object called "line"? And other similar questions which are often ignored when making such broad statements.

Comment: Random comment: I think this question passes the context test. If anything, it is a little broad, but considering the subject matter and line of thought included, I think it meets our standards for a question that can stay open. Just sayin'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something [I wrote about this viewpoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007373/basic-geometric-intuition-context-is-undergraduate-mathematics/2007496#2007496) earlier:

> A **better answer** to your misgivings (in the sense of being closer to the mainstream presentation) is probably simply to jump in with both feet and declare that **a line is not really made of points**.
>
> Decide to think of a line as *something that is in principle a different kind of thing from a bunch of points glued together*. You can do this and still acknowledge that points *exist* and some of them are on the line while others are not.
>
> It then turns out that all of the properties of a line segment (or a smooth curve in general) can be *recovered* from knowing which points lie on it and which don't. This doesn't necessarily mean that the points *make up* the line, but merely that the points tell us *enough* about the line.
>
> It is *technically convenient*, then, to speak about the *set of points on the line* as a placeholder for the line itself, when we're formalizing our reasoning -- for the pragmatic reason that we have a well-developed common machinery and notation for speaking of sets of things, which means that we don't need to introduce a new formalism for an entirely different kind of things.
>
> Some people are so comfortable with this representation that they happily declare that the line IS its set of points -- but nobody says you have to think of it that way. As long as you agree that the set of points *determines* the line, you can still communicate with people who prefer the other idea.

Why would one want to do that, you ask?

One reason is if it happens to be more comfortable philosophically for you to think that way. It's up to you whether it is or not, of course -- but, for example, the asker I wrote the above text for had gotten himself into conceptual trouble trying to imagine how points can have zero length and width, and yet combine to form a line of nonzero length.

Another reason is that you can *avoid talking about sets* at all for some purposes. Mathematicians use sets all the time, of course, but set theory does come at a foundational cost. For example, you can't have a *formal theory* that admits sets in a useful way without Gödel's incompleteness theorem applying, so the theory would necessarily be incomplete.

In particular, plain old *Euclidean geometry* can be formalized without having any concept of a set of points. That's what Euclid was doing, of course, though he missed a number of "intuitive" continuity properties. Hilbert tried to repair that, now explicitly considering "line" to be a primitive concept, but he failed to make it completely formal because formal logic was still being invented. (Later Tarski constructed an actual complete first-order theory of geometry, but he did it by omitting *any* concept of "line" at all, speaking instead of "collinear" as a relation between three points).

Comment: "In a useful way" are deliberate weasel words, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The "advantage" of thinking of points and lines in geometry as primitive objects related by incidence (I classify this as *synthetic geometry*) is that it is very general and easy to get started. The board is relatively free of clutter compared to starting the other way with "a plane is a set of points, and there are special subsets called lines with such and such properties..." and perhaps with something like "...and points have coordinates using $\mathbb R$..." (this is what I would call *coordinate* or *analytic* geometry.) You have to be familiar with the language of set theory to model everything with sets.

But for people who are comfortable with sets, sets are a very natural model for points, lines, and incidence.

One more thing: if you only care about Desarguesian geometry, you are free to adopt either viewpoint. This is the case for Euclidean metric  geometry, and yes, it is usually helpful to associate sets and measurements with geometric objects when first leaning geometry. In fact, plain synthetic geometry leads to more exotic geometries than those encodeable by coordinates over fields or even division rings. That is why I mentioned that it is more general than coordinate geometry.